# Store blog files

Tags: mysql, html

I wanna coding a blog website but I don't know how to store blog posts (include texts, images, etc) in server and how to make a form that I can type my post in.
It's such as posting a status in facebook 
Sorry, my english is so bad

Comment: this is not a free tutorial site. Instead we'll help you with a specific issue within your code. If you need to understand basics such as how to submit a form and store data, then please find a tutorial. As well as HTML and MySQL you will need to choose a server-side programming language which will execute on your webserver, e.g. PHP, NodeJS, Java, etc. - there are many others too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's  BLOB, CLOB, etc. data types to store binary data in MySQL.

Comment: This is true, but it's usually considered better for performance to store the files on disk somewhere, and in the database just maintain the path and filename. This way you avoid bloating the database, and also reading the file data from disk is usually faster than pulling the data out of the database as a stream.